# Azure storage table returns exception 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, azure, exception, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to create azure storage table and insert records into it using c#.
I have successfully created the table but it is giving me 400 Bad Request storage exception while inserting record into it.

after checking into debugger:

> StorageException.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorMessage

it is showing OutOfRangeInput error

> "One of the request inputs is out of range.\nRequestId:862fdbae-6002-000c-1e7c-ef9373000000\nTime:2019-04-10T09:06:05.9840359Z"

I took help of this thread [Azure table storage returns 400 Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859405/azure-table-storage-returns-400-bad-request)

and

- tried passing null into my entity model variables to see if any of record is out of range
- tried passing "test" in RowKey
- tried passing "1"/"test" in PartitionKey
- tried passing Guid.NewGuid().ToString() or ToAzureKeyString(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()) in RowKey
- tried passing DateTimeOffset.Now in Timestamp

still it is giving me the same error.
Here is my code:

```
public void GetGPSFileData(Config objConfig, TraceWriter log)
{
    try
    {
        BindData objData = new BindData();
        string date = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
        string storageTable = "TABLE" + date + objData.REPCODE;
        TableStorage tableStorage = new TableStorage(objData);
        CreateTableStorage(objConfig, storageTable, tableStorage, log);
    }
    catch (StorageException ex)
    {
        log.Info($"Storage Exception while reading GPS File Data from Azure Storage: " + ex.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorMessage + DateTime.Now);
        throw ex;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Info($"Error while reading GPS File Data from Azure Storage: " + ex.Message + DateTime.Now);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

TableStorage.cs

```
public class TableStorage: TableEntity
{
    public string CLIENTID { get; set; }
    public string REPCODE { get; set; }
    public int ENTRYNO { get; set; }
    public string DEVICEID { get; set; }
    public double LAT { get; set; }
    public double LNG { get; set; }
    public DateTime DATE_TIME { get; set; }

    public string PCODE { get; set; }
    public string PNAME { get; set; }
    public DateTime TXNDATE { get; set; }

    public TableStorage(BindData objData)
    {
        PartitionKey = objData.CLIENTID;
        RowKey = ToAzureKeyString(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now;

        CLIENTID = objData.CLIENTID;
        REPCODE = objData.REPCODE;
        ENTRYNO = objData.ENTRYNO;
        DEVICEID = objData.DEVICEID;
        LAT = objData.LAT;
        LNG = objData.LNG;
        DATE_TIME = objData.DATE_TIME;
        PCODE = objData.PCODE;
        PNAME = objData.PNAME;
        TXNDATE = objData.TXNDATE;
    }

    public string ToAzureKeyString(string str)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var c in str
            .Where(c => c != '/'
                        && c != '\\'
                        && c != '#'
                        && c != '/'
                        && c != '?'
                        && !char.IsControl(c)))
            sb.Append(c);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Create and Insert into Storage Table code:

```
public void CreateTableStorage(Config objConfig, string tableName, TableStorage tableStorage, TraceWriter log)
{
    try
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(objConfig.TABLE_STORAGE_CONN_STRING);
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
        table.CreateIfNotExists();

        TableOperation insert = TableOperation.Insert(tableStorage);
        table.Execute(insert);
    }
    catch(StorageException ex)
    {
        log.Info($"Storage Exception while inserting record into Table Storage: " + ex.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation.ErrorMessage + DateTime.Now);
        throw ex;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        log.Info($"Error while inserting record into Table Storage: " + ex.Message + DateTime.Now);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

TableStorage class's object contains:
[image: tableStorage obj]

What can be the issue? I'm totally new azure storage table.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does any chars like "/" in the string when you're trying to insert?

Comment: @IvanYang No, I checked every value before inserting, even tried passing empty or null string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is coming because of the value of `TXNDATE` attribute. If you look at the picture you shared, the value you're sending is `1/1/01` (i.e. `DateTime.MinValue`) whereas the minimum value allowed is `1/1/1601`.

Once you pass proper value for `TXNDATE`, you should not see this error.

Comment: Thanks, I tried passing date into TXNDATE and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there might be a default/parameter-less constructor missing from your class inheriting the TableEntity. The parameter-less constructor is very much needed to deserialize the object when recieved from the TableStorage.

Do refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55608767/unable-to-get-records-from-table-storage?answertab=active#tab-top).

The possible corrected code:

```
public class TableStorage: TableEntity
{
    public string CLIENTID { get; set; }
    public string REPCODE { get; set; }
    public int ENTRYNO { get; set; }
    public string DEVICEID { get; set; }
    public double LAT { get; set; }
    public double LNG { get; set; }
    public DateTime DATE_TIME { get; set; }

    public string PCODE { get; set; }
    public string PNAME { get; set; }
    public DateTime TXNDATE { get; set; }
    public TableStorage(){}//Added default constructor
    public TableStorage(BindData objData)
    {
        PartitionKey = objData.CLIENTID;
        RowKey = ToAzureKeyString(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now;

        CLIENTID = objData.CLIENTID;
        REPCODE = objData.REPCODE;
        ENTRYNO = objData.ENTRYNO;
        DEVICEID = objData.DEVICEID;
        LAT = objData.LAT;
        LNG = objData.LNG;
        DATE_TIME = objData.DATE_TIME;
        PCODE = objData.PCODE;
        PNAME = objData.PNAME;
        TXNDATE = objData.TXNDATE;
    }

    public string ToAzureKeyString(string str)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var c in str
            .Where(c => c != '/'
                        && c != '\\'
                        && c != '#'
                        && c != '/'
                        && c != '?'
                        && !char.IsControl(c)))
            sb.Append(c);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was passing 1/1/01 in TXNDATE, after passing proper date into TXNDATE, it worked successfully. Even if i don't create parameterless constructor in TableStorage it is working, do i really need to create parameterless constructor?

Comment: I think yes you will need it as the Read operation won't work without it. So currently I believe you are not Reading any data from the storage but when you will be doing you will be needing the parameter-less constructor.

Comment: Yes, It was giving me an error while reading the data

Comment: Hopefully doing this will also solve your reading problem :)

Comment: Yes, It solved. Thanks :)